# How to squash commits in branches

Tags: git, svn, git-filter-branch, squash

I am importing an old svn repo into git.  At one point a folder was renamed in all branches.  This was done in svn by creating a duplicate with history, followed by a delete of the original on a second commit.  So I have a repo that looks like this:

```
A -> B -> C -> D* -> E* -> F -> G -> H
      \-> 1 -> 2* -> 3* - > 4 -/
```

Where D/E and 2/3 are the commits I want to squash.
The reason for squashing is that while svn knows of "duplicate with history", git doesn't see this as a rename since the original files weren't removed until the next commit, and I lose history on blame at this point.

I've experimented with some rebase scripts which work, but they also flatten all my branches.  The above is a seriously simplified version of what I have to do, which is why I really need scripts as I can't do it manually.  There are over 1,000 branches throughout the history of the SVN repo and probably a dozen parallel branches where this change was done (all at the same time).

The git repo has not been published yet, so maintaining hashes is irrelevant.  I assume I'll need to use some filter-branch script, but I'm still trying to figure out how to manage that which is what I was hoping I might get help with here.  I *can* provide the sha1 of every commit that needs squashed and its parent.

Comment: checkout 4, git rebase -i 1, change 2 and 3 commits to squash, they will squash up into 1

Comment: This leaves me with an orphaned 4', which then I have to rebase the rest of my tree onto.  I have 7 years of history and nearly 100K commits and all the branches and merges that comes with that after this point, which makes manually rebasing and fixing this history very complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `git filter-branch` using `--parent-filter` to replace any appearance of `D`'s SHA with `C`'s SHA. You can also look into `.git/info/grafts` or [`git replace`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace), which might be simpler than writing a `--parent-filter` and can be made permanent with a `filter-branch`.

**Update:** As @torek says, you should definitely use [`git replace`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace). To use a real-life example, here's a rename from `readme.md` to `README.md` was executed with an intermediate rename to `README1.md`: https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/compare/dahlbyk:2b9342c...dahlbyk:57394c5. Let's call `2b9342c` your `C` and `57394c5` your `E`:

```
$ git tag E 57394c5
$ git tag C 2b9342c
$ git tag G 450d8f1
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate C~..G
*   450d8f1 (tag: G) Merge pull request #320 ...
|\  
| * 941935c Fix a few kbd / missing markdown issues/
| * f13dcf9 Upcase readme and have more prompt examples.
| * 57394c5 (tag: E) Now rename to README.md.
| * eb79ef2 Prepare to upcase README.md filename.
* |   536c57f Merge pull request #319 ...
|\ \  
| |/  
|/|   
| * 7fafb7b Speed up Get-GitStatus
|/  
* 2b9342c (tag: C) Merge pull request #313 ...
```

To pretend that the intermediate move never happened, I can `replace` `E`'s parent (`E~`) with its grandparent (`E~2` = `C`):

```
$ git log --stat --oneline C..E
57394c5 Now rename to README.md.
 README1.md => README.md | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
eb79ef2 Prepare to upcase README.md filename.
 readme.md => README1.md | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
$ git replace E~ C
$ git log --stat --oneline C..E
57394c5 Now rename to README.md.
 readme.md => README.md | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
eb79ef2 Merge pull request ...
```

Finally, a `filter-branch` will make the changes permanent:

```
$ git filter-branch -- ^C G E  # For demo, only rewrite G & E afer C
$ git log --graph --oneline --decorate C~..G
*   fcfd345 (tag: G) Merge pull request #320 ...
|\  
| * fa76267 Fix a few kbd / missing markdown issues/
| * 4900687 Upcase readme and have more prompt examples.
| * b25aa5a (tag: E) Now rename to README.md.
* |   536c57f Merge pull request #319 ...
|\ \  
| |/  
|/|   
| * 7fafb7b Speed up Get-GitStatus
|/  
* 2b9342c (tag: C) Merge pull request #313 ...
```

---

For your purposes, you'll do something like:

```
$ git replace E~ E~2
$ git replace 3~ 3~2
$ git filter-branch -- ^A --all
```

**Update 2**:

> The commit message I get is off of E, which I don't care about. I'd rather have D's commit message (or a script provided message).

To keep `D`'s commit metadata, I would suggest starting over and using a `--commit-filter` to specify `E`'s `tree` (`git cat-file -p E`) for `D` (and that `E` should be skipped), e.g.

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
  if [ "$GIT_COMMIT" = "SHA of D" ];
  then
    git commit-tree "TREE of E" -p "SHA of C";
  elif [ "$GIT_COMMIT" = "SHA of E" ];
  then
    skip_commit "$@";
  else
    git commit-tree "$@";
  fi;
  ' -- ^A E G
```

Comment: If you get stuck, leave an update or comment with your progress and we can try to help.

Comment: For this case, I would recommend running `git replace` twice: first, to make an `E'` that points back to `C`, with Git using `E'` instead of `E`; and then again to make `3'` that points back to `1`, with Git using `3'` instead of `3`. Then, as you said, optionally run `git filter-branch` to cement the replacements and discard the original `D-E` and `2-3` entirely.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't notice the same operation was needed for `2-3`. Updated.

Comment: This is great, my end tree is exactly what I want!  Thank you!  I didn't know about Git Replace.
2 Questions with this:

1) What is the ^A in your filter-branch?  I am familiar with the rest of the notations, but not sure what that means.  I assume it marks commit A as a start point to avoid filtering anything before?

2) The commit message I get is off of E, which I don't care about.  I'd rather have D's commit message (or a script provided message).  This isn't a showstopper though, what you've given me already is enough to move forward!  Thank you!

Comment: `^A` means "commits not reachable from `A`" (described in [`git rev-list` help](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)), which is just an optimization for your `filter-branch` since you don't need to rewrite any commits before `A`.

The easiest way to change `D`'s commit message would probably be to use a `--msg-filter` that essentially does a search/replace from new message to the old. Another option would be to start over, skipping `git-replace` in favor of a `--commit-filter` that specifies `E^{tree}` for `D` and skips commit `E`.